# Making a unique combination of items from each column

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
    Person 1  Person 2  Person 3   Person 4
a      Apple     Apple       Yam       Beer
b     Orange    Orange   Doritos     Cheese
c  Pineapple  Nintendo     Apple      Sushi
d      Pizza    Cheese    Orange  Pineapple
e    Doritos     Fanta     Pizza     Orange
f       Coke    Fajita      Cake       Coke
g Strawberry     Juice      Beer        Tea
h Blackberry                           Yam
i      Sushi
```

Each column represents each person and each row is an item that each corresponding (row) person likes.

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that can give me a list of unique combinations, using each item only once and at the same time giving a person one item that the person wants.

Something like:

```
1)
    Person 1  Person 2  Person 3   Person 4
       Apple    Orange       Yam       Beer

2)
    Person 1  Person 2  Person 3   Person 4
       Apple    Orange       Yam     Cheese
```

.. so on.

Could please someone guide me how to approach this problem? I am a novice in python.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the solution to the [Stable Marriage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Without libraries:

```
pools = ['Apple', 'Orange', ...], ['Apple', 'Orange', ...], [...], [...]]
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool if y not in x]

print(result)
```

Comment: Needs to be `result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool if y not in x]` to filter out combinations that have duplicate items.

Comment: `set(result)` will raise an error because lists cannot be hashed, you can either go with Jon's comment or keep tuples instead of lists inside `result`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use itertools.product() to generate the combinations, then select the valid ones (no duplicate items) with set().

Something like this:

```
from itertools import product

person_1 = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pineapple', ...]
person_2 = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Nintendo', ...]
person_3 = ['Yam', 'Doritos', 'Apple', ...]
person_4 = ['Beer', 'Cheese', 'Sushi', ...]


for p in product(person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4):
    if len(p) == len(set(p)):
        print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


d= {"Person 1" : ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pineapple', ...],"Person 2" : ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Nintendo', ...],"Person 3" : ['Yam', 'Doritos', 'Apple', ...],"Person 4" : ['Beer', 'Cheese', 'Sushi', ...]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df=df.drop_duplicates()
df=df.dropna(axis=0)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pools = [['Apple', 'Orange','Pineapple'], ['Apple', 'Orange','pizza'],['Apple', 
         'Orange','pizza','beer']]

results = []
for pool in pools:  
    results.append([item for item in pool if item not in results][0])

Output: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'pizza']
```